# Datagrid Row background color when using contextmenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, background, row

please help me
When im using context menu for row datagrid, the background changes to a different color.
How to fix it?
[standart background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujBfW.png)
[background when using context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKtWj.png)

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Model.FlatModel}" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserSortColumns="False" RowHeight="20" >
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="#A6D8FF"/>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>

            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
          
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this context menu, It works well even when multiple items are selected at the same time.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=ContextMenu.IsOpen}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).